# MHD pump liquid metal flow speed

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, magnetohydrodynamics

a rather simple question, are there any studies or some information about the flow speed of liquid metal inside a tube?

My setup is basically a 50cm diameter circular tube (could be another diameter) that is thin where the inner tube diameter is said 1cm, now half the tube is filled with liquid metal (mercury or Galinstan) and the other half is filled wither with an inert gas or a liquid with dielectric properties, given I pass current through the liquid metal and have a perpendicular B field going through the tube, how fast I could make the metal circulate around the tube?
Any ideas?

[image]